# Responsive Divs not stacking on mobile

Tags: css, mobile

I had this working correctly earlier, but as I kept editing, I must have done something and now the two divs do not stack on mobile view. I found a post similar, but the example site provided isn't working anymore, so the answer wasn't really helpful without the context.

I tried adjusting the floats, but cannot seem to get the result I need, and I didn't think it was that anyway since it *was* working previously. Any have any ideas what I might be able to adjust to resolve this?

```css
.eventcontainer {
  bottom: 0;
  margin: .5%;
  width: 95%;
}
.eventleft {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 700px;
}
.eventright {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: left;
  border: 2px solid #9cc;
  padding: 2%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .eventcontainer {
    bottom: 0;
    margin: .5%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .eventleft {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 575px;
  }
  .eventright {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .eventcontainer {
    max-width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .leftcontent {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .rightcontent {
    float: none;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="eventcontainer">
  <div class="eventleft">
    <h2 class="activities">Student Activities</h2>
    <p class="activities">CMS students participate ... blah blah</p>
    <h2 class="activities">Social Media Awareness</h2>
    <p class="activities">This week some of the students and staff ... yada yada</p>
    <p class="activities">In light of this week’s incidents ... yak yak</p>
  </div>
  <div class="eventright">
    <h2>Events</h2>
    <h3>Parent Teacher Conferences</h3>
    <h4>Thurs, Nov 20, 2014</h4>
    <h5>2:00pm - 7:00pm</h5>
    <p>The quarterly Parent Teacher Conferences will be held on the Thursday before Thanksgiving break. Come meet your child's teachers and stop by the auditorium for the student art exhibit!</p>
    <h3>Thanksgiving Break</h3>
    <h4>Nov 24 - Nov 28, 2014</h4>
    <p>No school the week of Thanksgiving!</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

- the activities classes are just styling of the text itself, not pertinent to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You defined more than 100% width on mobile view. the easiest fix is to apply:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

... to all or just to selectors you mentioned above. The other way would be to set margin + padding in percents, all of them sum with element width (also the border). You should read [this interesting article](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) about box-sizing property.

Comment: Crud. I just realized I pasted in the wrong code for mobile. It should be:

Comment: .eventcontainer {
      max-width: 95%;
      margin: 0 auto;
     }
 
  .leftcontent {
      float: none;
  text-align: center;
     }
 
  .rightcontent {
      float: none;
  text-align: left;
     }

Comment: Whatever, I told you what the problem was - more width than 100%. If you say for `.element{width: 30%; padding: 10%; margin: 5%; border: 2px;}` total width it takes from parent element is `30%+2*20%+2*10%+2*2px=90%+4px`. With `box-sizing: border-box` total width would be `30%`.